# Why am I getting a "Function is unused" error?

Tags: swift, closures

I'm trying to unit test a closure that works just fine, but for whatever reason the compiler throws this `Function is unused` error in the test. I'm passing the parameter. What am I missing?

[image]

This is the closure's definition:

```
configuration.router.didSelectProduct = { navigationController in
    { product in
      let vc = More.build(navigationController: navigationController)
      navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
  }
```

Note that the closure variable is optional so I'm force unwrapping it for simplicity.

Comment: Consider upload all code and errors as text instead of image. For more, please refer to: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `didSelectProduct` is a nested closure, and you are missing the parameter for the inner closure. You can provide a second parameter like:

```swift
didSelectProduct!(navController)(someProduct)
```